# React - Values in array between 0 & 1

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to set the array to have decimal values representing percentages (0%, 5%, 10%) however React doesn't accept these values. How do I present my array with decimal values?

```
const marks = [
    { value: 0},
    { value: .05},
    { value: .10}
  ];
```

Comment: What do you mean by `React doesn't accept these values`?

Comment: Can you provide more information? these values are perfectly accepted in javascript

Answer (score 0):

You may try this, pass your array in `convertToDecimal`

```
const convertToDecimal = (arr)  =>{
    let newArr=[];
    arr.map(item =>
        newArr.push(item.value*100));
    return newArr;
}

convertToDecimal(marks)
```